# Unrecognized option 'profile:v'

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to run the command

```
ffmpeg -i webcamrecording.flv -s 1024x768 -profile:v baseline webcamrecording.mp4
```

as part of an attempt to produce an mp4 that can play in a video tag. I get the message

```
Unrecognized option 'profile:v'
```

Is my ffmpeg too old? I have version .6.5.0.

Answer (score 2):

> Is my ffmpeg too old? I have version .6.5.0.

Yes. That option probably was added later, or at least the version with the stream specifier `:v`. You could try using `-profile` without the `:v`, or `-vprofile` (which [was undocumented](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/2634/how-do-i-specify-baseline-h264-profile-using-ffmbc/2876#2876) for some FFmpeg versions up to 0.9), or just install a recent build.

To do that, go to their [download page](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html) and [compile it yourself](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/CompilationGuide) or install a static build for your operating system.

Comment: Thanks! I tried that and got                                         [NULL @ 0x478f4a0]Unable to parse option value "baseline": undefined constant or missing (

Comment: So you're on a recent FFmpeg now? What exactly is "that" you tried? ? `vprofile` or `profile`? What happens when you specify `ffmpeg -i input.flv -c:v libx264 -profile:v baseline output.mp4`? (Please update your question with the full, uncut command line output.)

Comment: Sorry, "that" is vprofile. Then I tried -vcodec libx264 -vpre slow -vpre ipod640 -b 250k -bt 50k -acodec libfaac -ab 56k -ac 2 and- it worked! Thanks for your help slhck, I wouldn't have gotten there without you.

Comment: Glad I could help. `-vprofile` is the undocumented workaround. This means that you're still on an old version though, since that was fixed 10 months ago. Also the `-vpre` option is deprecated, and newer versions of FFmpeg won't allow you to use it. Consider upgrading if you can, though, since you won't be able to get much support for old releases (here, and on the FFmpeg mailing list, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Works for me good sir

```
$ ffmpeg -i webcamrecording.flv -s 1024x768 -profile:v baseline webcamrecording
.mp4
ffmpeg version N-49069-gc74d465 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jan 20 2013 23:44:08 with gcc 4.7.2 (GCC)

Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=   63 fps=0.0 q=28.0 size=     124kB time=00:00:02.88 bitrate= 351.9kbits/
frame=  103 fps=102 q=28.0 size=     478kB time=00:00:04.60 bitrate= 849.2kbits/
frame=  137 fps= 91 q=28.0 size=     806kB time=00:00:06.04 bitrate=1091.5kbits/
```